# Why is integration by parts not working on this problem?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate the following integral using integration by parts:

$$\int\frac{x}{1+e^x}dx$$

However, using $u = x$, $du = 1$, $dv = \frac{1}{1+e^x}$, $v = x-\log(e^x+1)$, I keep getting that the  integral is $-\text{Li}_2(-e^x)+\frac{x^2}{2}-x\log(1+e^x)$, but Wolfram Alpha says that the integral is $\text{Li}_2(-e^{-x})-x\log(e^{-x}+1)$.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried differentiating your answer to see if you get the original integrand back?

Comment: Write $\mathrm dx$ also in your integral.

Comment: If $u=x$ then it is certainly true that $\frac{du}{dx}=1$, but it is not true that $du=1$.

Comment: This is a beautiful example of a very common mistake in the real world. I've seen a lot of professors in engineering and science make it. You're in very good company.

Answer (score 52):

Who says you went wrong? Subtract the two answers

$$-\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^x) - \operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{-x})+\frac{x^2}{2}-x\log(1+e^x) +x\log(e^{-x}+1)$$

$$=\frac{\pi^2}{6} +x^2 -x\log(1+e^x) +x\log(e^{-x}+1)$$

And since $x^2 = x\log e^x$, the rest of the terms collapse and we get that difference between the two answers is $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, a constant.

Comment: Perhaps also cite the identity connecting $\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^x)$ and  $\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{-x})$.